# Clean server-side session files - Flask-Session using filesystem

Tags: python, session, flask, server-side, flask-session

I chose to use a **server-side** session management with Flask using Flask-Session.

I store the data using `filesystem` and as expected, these files are stored under a `/flask_session` folder in my config directory.

Here is how I set this up in my `__init__.py`

```
# __init__.py

from flask_session import Session

[...]

app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = config.SECRET_KEY
sess = Session()
sess.init_app(app)
```

As expected, session files generated & stored under `/flask_session`

```
▾ flask_session/
        1695e5cbf9b4edbbbb82a8ef1fad89ae
        192761f7ce8e3cbf3ca11665133b7794
        2029240f6d1128be89ddc32729463129
        ...
```

**Question is:** Are these files automatically removed by `flask_session` after a specific amount of time (ie. as the session stored client-side)? If yes, is it possible to decrease/increase this timing?

Comment: did you try to set [PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/config/#PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME)?

Comment: Thanks @DanilaGanchar, indeed config for Flask-Session are the same builtin config than in Flask itself (related to session).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Danila Ganchar commented, using `PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME` allows to control the session expiration time.

Flask-Session use the same builtin config than Flask itself (related to session).   From [Flask-Session](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/) doc:

> The following configuration values are builtin configuration values
>   within Flask itself that are related to session. They are all
>   understood by Flask-Session, for example, you should use
>   PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME to control your session lifetime.

Example:

```
# __init__.py

from flask_session import Session
from datetime import timedelta

app.config['SESSION_PERMANENT'] = True
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
app.config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME'] = timedelta(hours=5)

# The maximum number of items the session stores 
# before it starts deleting some, default 500
app.config['SESSION_FILE_THRESHOLD'] = 100  

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = config.SECRET_KEY
sess = Session()
sess.init_app(app)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will notice I import **Session** from **flask_session.**init**** Also I just call **Session(app)** I do not use **sess.init_app(app)**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import annotations

from datetime import timedelta
from flask import Flask
from flask_session.__init__ import Session


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = "www.mslscript.com"
app.secret_key = config.secret
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = True
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
app.config['SESSION_FILE_THRESHOLD'] = 250
app.config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME'] = timedelta(hours=10)

Session(app)

from website.views import views
from website.auth import auth
app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')
```