# Flask-Session (filesystem): session files are not deleted after PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME

Tags: flask, flask-session

I am trying to test server-side Flask sessions using [Flask-Session](https://flask-session.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I am attempting to have sessions last only a minute in order to test that the session's files get deleted, but even when I set the session time to one (1) minute, the session's files are not cleared. I am trying to implement something similar the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53841909/clean-server-side-session-files-flask-session-using-filesystem), but it doesn't seem to be working...

Here's my simple application:

```
# IMPORTS
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, session
from flask_session import Session
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


# APP SETUP
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
app.config['SESSION_PERMANENT'] = True
app.config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME'] = timedelta(minutes=1)
app.secret_key = "czOWE9w7nfe7Z6UpLPaEHC2NXMJzUI57"
Session(app)
```

As I expect, the files are being generated under /flask_session:
[image of folder with files in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PNXa.png)

However, due to `app.config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME'] = timedelta(minutes=1)` I am expecting at least one of the following to occur:

1. after one minute the files will be deleted while still using the application.
2. one minute *after closing the window* the files will be deleted.

Neither of these outcomes occur :( What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flask-Session uses [Cachelib's File backend](https://cachelib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/file/). If you look at [its source code](https://github.com/pallets-eco/cachelib/blob/main/src/cachelib/file.py#L241):

```
def set(
    self,
    key: str,
    value: _t.Any,
    timeout: _t.Optional[int] = None,
    mgmt_element: bool = False,
) -> bool:
    # Management elements have no timeout
    if mgmt_element:
        timeout = 0
    # Don't prune on management element update, to avoid loop
    else:
        self._prune()
    ...
```

you see that it calls the `_prune()` method at the beginning of key-set method. So the expired elements will be cleared at the next time you set a new element *and* the conditions for clearing are satisfied. It's because you don't have a background worker/cron that clears automatically the expired elements. Furthermore there is the file count threshold setting: `SESSION_FILE_THRESHOLD` that is by default 500. You need to decrease that as well if you want to increase the frequency of clearing.